# Excel find values returned by a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has values being returned by formulas. When attempting to seach for these values using the keyboard combination CTRL-F, it returns that it cannot be found even though it exists.

How can i use CTRL-F to find the values? The version of Microsoft Excel is 2010.

Comment: Do you have the exact value or do you need the full Ctrl+F functionality?

Comment: @Paul - panhandel's answer helped resolve the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The find window has options, craftily hidden behind the "Options > >" button to look in "formulas", "values", or "comments".  The default is formulas, so just switch that to values.

Comment: It is indeed hidden away.